# How can I pass 'CommandParameter' down to children elements in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

There are many buttons that have common CommandParameter like the below, but more buttons, more messy.

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo1Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommonParam, Source={StaticResource CommonObj}}" />
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo2Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommonParam, Source={StaticResource CommonObj}}" />
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo3Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommonParam, Source={StaticResource CommonObj}}" />
   ...
   ...
   ...
</StackPanel>
```

I want to pass CommandParameter on the parent element down to children elements, so, I want to make the above code like the below in the end.

```
<StackPanel CommandParameter="{Binding CommonParam, Source={StaticResource CommonObj}}">
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo1Command}" />
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo2Command}" />
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo3Command}" />
   ...
   ...
   ...
</StackPanel>
```

Is it possible? If so, It'll be very thanksful if you suggest what I should learn to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is possible. all buttons can share common style where default parameter set.

it is not "passing CommandParameter on the parent element down to children elements"

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" 
                    Value="{Binding CommonParam, Source={StaticResource CommonObj}}"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo1Command}" />
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo2Command}" />
   <Button Command="{Binding Foo3Command}" />
   <!--other code-->
</StackPanel>
```